# Minimal size of subsets $A,B$ in a finite group $G$ such that $AB=G$

Tags: gr.group-theory, co.combinatorics

Given a finite group $G$ with $N$ elements what are the "smallest" possible subsets
$A,B$ of $G$ such that $G=AB$ (ie. every element of $G$ is a product of an element in $A$
and an element in $B$)?

We have of course $\sharp(A)\sharp(B)\geq N$
but can one always find two subsets $A,B$ of size roughly $\sqrt N$ with the property $G=AB$?
Since I do not know the optimal answer a good definition of "roughly" 
should be part of an answer (one can surely not do better than
$A,B$ of size $O(1)+\sqrt N$ but I guess this is much to optimistic.
It is perhaps more reasonable to hope for $\sqrt N$ times something bounded).

The optimal answer $A,B$ of size (at most) $1+\sqrt N$ works for cyclic groups: take 
$A=\mathbb N\left\lceil \sqrt N\right\rceil\cap \{0,\dots,N-1 \}$
and $ B= \{ 0,1,\dots,\left\lfloor \sqrt{N} \right \rfloor \} $ in $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z=
\{0,\dots,N-1\}$.

On the other hand, if $G$ has a (not-necessarily normal) subgroup $H$ of size roughly $\sqrt{N}$ one can 
consider $A=H$ and take for $B$ coset-representantives.

Combining the two constructions we get a nearly optimal result for abelian groups.

Is there for example a sequence of "bad" groups $G_i$ such that, say
$$\left((1+\sharp(A_i))(1+\sharp(B_i))-\sharp(G_i)\right)\Big/\sqrt{\sharp(G_i)}$$
is unbounded for every (sequence of) subsets $A_i,B_i\subset G_i$ 
such that $G_i=A_iB_i$? (The existence of such a sequence would of course
the hope for the existence of $A,B$ of size $O(1)\sqrt{\sharp(G)}$ (with $AB=G$)
in every finite group $G$.

Comment: Interesting question! I only made the braces appear, by adding extra backslashes. 

Comment: For finite simple groups of Lie type I believe you can always cook up a subgroup of order $N^{1/2 + f(r)}$ where $r$ the rank and $f(r)$ is some function of $r$ that tends to zero as $r$ increases. Then, taking coset representatives, as you suggest, you've got yourself a not-far-from-optimal $A$ and $B$, at least for large rank. I think something similar will work for $Alt(n)$ where $r$ is now the number of primes dividing $n$ (or something).

So if I were looking for non-abelian simple counter-examples I'd look at low-rank groups of Lie type, or $Alt(n)$ for $n$ prime-ish.

Comment: [Comment continued]: I thought about simple groups first because it seems reasonably clear that you can reduce this question to one about simple groups by considering a composition series (?) I say "reasonably clear" but I haven't written down a proof...

Comment: I think you will get close to the optimum in most nilpotent groups by taking $A$ to be a subgroup, since if $G$ is nilpotent, every divisor of $|G|$ is the order of some subgroup of $G$.  That said, this doesn't work if $|G|=p^n$ where $n$ is a fixed odd number and $p$ varies, so you would need to combine it somehow with the strategy for cyclic groups.

Comment: So, the strategy when A = H is a subgroup generalizes to A being your favorite set with $|A A^{-1}| = O(|A|)$, by a similar packing argument (if you accept a constant factor at the end).  The aim is then to find such a set with $|A| \approx \sqrt{N}$.

This gives rise to the cyclic example above, and should do what Colin Reid wants for nilpotent groups (see above).  I don't know Whether you could use something like this to avoid the use of CFSG in the general case.





Comment: Jack Button has answered the question by citation of [Kozma and Lev](http://www.springerlink.com/index/h94n15h58m2843j1.pdf), though one really doesn't find a subgroup of size around $\sqrt N$, but you find a subgroup $H$ *at least* this size by Classification (for instance of course, extraspecials of order $p^3$ have no subgroup "near" size $\sqrt{p^3}$), and pass via transversals (Lemma 2) from $H$ to $G$. Here is a slightly different question in the spirit of additive combinatorics.

Comment: Here is a slightly different question in the spirit of additive combinatorics. Take a subset $S$ of size $p^{9/10}$ in ${\bf Z}_p$. Can you find $A$ and $B$ of size less than $1000p^{9/20}$ such that $AB=S$? I think that is more the case where an probability analysis can be more robust. In general, ask how large $S$ must be (in terms of $p$) for subset to act more like the ambient group w.r.t decomposition.

Comment: A more robust method for getting effective backslashes is to enclose the paragraph in "p" tags.

Answer (score 11):

For square root of N times something bounded, this can be done with A=B (and the bound
being 4 over the square root of 3) according to

Kozma and Lev, Bases and decomposition numbers of finite groups
Arch. Math. (Basel) 58 (1992), 417-424

which seems to do as you say, namely find a subgroup of order about the square root of
N (via an appeal to CFSG).

It wouldn't surprise me if the O(1)+square root of N case is open.

Comment: That's a very nice result!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how interesting my answer can be after a comment by Ben Green, but this would be too long for a comment, and I hope it can be helpful, somehow.

Your question is tightly related to the behavior of a function first introduced, afaik, by the late M. Kervaire, and studied to some extent by the same author (and his students) and A. Plagne (and his students); see, e.g., the references in É. Balandraud, *The isoperimetric method in non-abelian groups with an application to optimally small sumsets*, IJNT, Vol. 4, No. 6 (2008), 927-958. To wit, for a group $\mathbb G$ let $\mu_\mathbb{G}$ be the function

  $\mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N \cup \{\infty\}: (s,t) \mapsto \min\{|AB|: A, B \in\mathcal P(\mathbb G), |A| = s, |B| = t\}$.

Now, if $\mathbb G_1, \mathbb G_2, \ldots$ is a sequence of finite groups with $|\mathbb G_n| = n$ for each $n$, your question does essentially refer, if I'm not missing anything, to the asymptotic behavior of the restriction of $\mu_n := \mu_{\mathbb G_n}$ to a subset $S_n \times T_n$ of $\mathbb N^2$ such that $\min(S_n, T_n) = O(1) + \sqrt{n}$ and $\max(S_n, T_n)= O(1) + \sqrt{n}$ for $n \to \infty$, for which you'd like to have $\mu_n(S_n,T_n) = n$ for all sufficiently large $n$, and "uniformly" with respect to the actual choice of the sequences $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$.

This in turn has a seemingly intimate, but still unclear relation with the classical Cauchy-Davenport theorem and its generalizations, which is something that I myself am trying to investigate with the aid of Alain and Éric.

**Edit.** As pointed out by quid in the comments below, it is better, with respect to the question raised by the OP, to re-write the above in terms of the "dual" of $\mu_\mathbb{G}$, namely the function

  ${\rm M}_\mathbb{G}: \mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N: (s,t) \mapsto \max\{|AB|: A, B \in\mathcal P(\mathbb G), |A| = s, |B| = t\}$.

But now you would rather check out if, for a certain sequence $\mathbb G_1, \mathbb G_2, \ldots$ of groups, it holds $\limsup_n (n - \max_{s \in S_n, t \in T_n} {\rm M}_{\mathbb G}(s,t)) \ne 0$, "uniformly" with respect to $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$.

Comment: It seems to me what you say is rather somehow 'dual' or 'at the opposite end' to what is asked. Consider the case of a cyclic group of square order $m^2$. As explained in the question in thsi case one *can* choose $A$, $B$ of size $m$. Yet it is not at all true that *every* choice of sets of this size will do (take the subgroup or two cosets of it of order m). Put differently, the question asks for conditions when *max* |AB| over certain sets A,B is the order of the group, not min.  

Comment: On second reading: sorry, I did not pay enough attention to the "uniformly" you mentioned. So, my first comment is not completely to the point. However, I still think that the two problems are at opposite ends of the spectrum. But then there can be no harm in having this related type of problem mentioned.   

Comment: @quid. You're right. Replacing min with max is certainly closer to the spirit of the OP. I guess this is what you meant by the term "dual".

Answer (score 1):

In general, one expects to need $N\log N$ "random" products to cover a set of size $N$, by coupon collecting analysis. So my intuition is that you need more than just $\sqrt N$ elements in the sets $A$ and $B$, closer to $\sqrt{N\log N}$.

The odds of covering an $N$-element set with $cN$ selections (fixed c as $N\rightarrow\infty$) is approximately $e^{cN}/N!$ I think, and you only have ${N\choose \sqrt{cN}}^2$ possible choices of $(A,B)$, and this is only of size $N^{2\sqrt{cN}}$, much smaller than the dominant $N!$.

But the above is just randomness theory, not invoking theory of groups.

Comment: Is this exactly "coupon collecting analysis"? For each choice of B = {b_1,..,b_k} you can try and estimate the probability that AB is all of G, if A is chosen randomly. But then you have to sum over a large selection of B's, and the triangle inequality may be too crude. In fact, I posed as an open problem (Barbados workshop, March 2012) the question of deciding whether the log N should really be there. Can Z/NZ be covered by O(N^{1/2}) translates of a random set A of size N^{1/2}?